Deploying Vite + React creating a white screen on IOS
So I am deveoloping a Vite React Webapp and deploying it on Fly.io. It works on every Browser except on IOs. There every time i enter the website, my site goes blank. Now sadly i cant read the console on my IPhone therefore I have no Information about the error.
However this thread (React + Vite App Not Loading on iOS When Wrapped with Cordova (White Screen Issue)) provided a solution that fixes the issue but created a new one. My service worker stop working.
I have already tried to edit vite.config.ts:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { VitePWA } from 'vite-plugin-pwa'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    VitePWA({
      registerType: 'autoUpdate',
      devOptions: {
        enabled: true,
      },
      workbox: {
        skipWaiting: true,
        clientsClaim: true,
        globPatterns: ['**/*.{js,css,html,png,jpg,svg,json,webmanifest,ico}'],
      },
      includeAssets: ['icons'],
      strategies: 'injectManifest',
      srcDir: 'src/sw',
      filename: 'sw.ts',
      injectManifest: {
        swDest: 'dist/sw.js',
      },
      manifest: {
        name: 'WTT - APP',
        short_name: 'WTT',
        description: 'An app to track user data',
        theme_color: '#161618',
        start_url: '/',
        display: 'standalone',
        orientation: 'portrait',
        icons: [
          {
            src: '/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png',
            sizes: '192x192',
            type: 'image/png',
          },
          {
            src: '/icons/android-chrome-512x512.png',
            sizes: '512x512',
            type: 'image/png',
          },
          {
            src: "/icons/apple-touch-icon.png",
            sizes: "180x180",
            type: "image/png",
          }
        ],
      }
    })
  ],
  base: '/',
  publicDir: 'public',
  build: {
    minify: 'terser',
  }
})

I tried to implement solutions that helped othe people, like specifying base: '/' and using build.minify = 'terser'. These solutions didn't work out either. What am I missing here?
